# Set .exe affinity without shortcut

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, affinity

I do not want to state an incomplete XY problem, so here's the full situation:

## X

I am running builds in Visual Studio on my Windows 7 machine, using both parallel builds and parallel compilation. Disabling either of these is not an option.

My problem is that occasionally, this spawns so many `cl.exe` (compiler) processes that the whole machine slows down, UI gets unresponsive etc.

The machine has 12 effective cores (6 w/hyperthreading).

## Y

My idea to solve this problem is to restrict `cl` to only 11 or 10 of the cores available, so that it cannot turn the whole machine unresponsive. Unfortunately, I was not able to find a way to do so.

I've found ways to set application affinity by using a shortcut (`.lnk`) to the application, but that is not applicable in my situation because `cl.exe` is launched by Visual Studio internally, and not directly by me.

I've also found ways of setting the affinity of a process already running, but that's not useful for me either (if nothing else, the `cl.exe` processes end and get spawned throughout the build, they're not long-running ones).

I am looking for a way to do the **Y** part, but alternative ways to solve the **X** problem (unresponsiveness caused by too many processes running, stopping, and starting) are welcome solutions as well.

Comment: Can't you just lower number of parallel builds? [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0xettzf.aspx)

Comment: @PTwr Unfortunately, no. As I mentioned, it's a combination of parallel builds (what the MSDN thing talks about) and parallel compilation (`/MP` switch). And I can't get rid of either one, because the builds also involve Fortran, which only has parallel builds.

Comment: Ah, then I guess it will be just question of setting permanent affinity then. I think I used [tool like this](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/bang-dual-processing-buck,815-3.html) or something similar in past. Or you can set up virtual machine with limited cores ;)

Comment: @PTwr That sounds like an answer to me - basically, my question is "how to set parmanent affinity?" This makes "with this free tool" a valid answer IMO.

Comment: I would prefer to test it first by myself, for now its just random memory recall.